# Android drawables (icons) list

Tags: android, reference, icons, drawable

I am trying to find a visual list of available icons in Android that comes with the sdk.

The ones I am interested in is the 2.3 gingerbread icons. There s a nice [reference](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/) but it is a snapshot of 2.2 icons ( and apparently they are not the same, for example I couldnT find "addcontact" in 2.3 sdk)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this my friend:

http://vidarvestnes.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-23-drawables-gingerbread.html

Comment: Thanks Matt. Pity if there s no official ref tho.

Comment: A lot of the images are private, change during OS versions and before ICS can be removed or changed by OEM custom skins etc. If you are going to use these I recommend copying them into your project.